# how to install rospack/rosstack

Tags: rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I'm new to ros and installed fuerte(OS Ubuntu 12.04),

the documentation says rospack/rosstack are stand-alone-tools in this version,
but there is no description where to get the tool.

My guess was, that something like "sudo easy_install -U rospack" would do the trick, which it does not.

Any suggestions what I might need to download or what the correct bash-command is?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34625/how-to-install-rospack/rosstack/) by [Flowers](https://answers.ros.org/users/2441/flowers/) on ROS Answers with karma: 342 on 2012-05-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Flowers](https://answers.ros.org/users/2441/flowers/) on 2012-05-23**:
thx Tinne, dunno why, but it seems like I used an outdated installationguide, where ROS_PACKET_PATH was set within the .bashrc :-)

**Comment by [Tinne De Laet](https://answers.ros.org/users/137/tinne-de-laet/) on 2012-05-24**:
Thanks for the update.
If my answer solved your question/problem you can click the check mark. This will help people in the future for finding the correct answer. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you should just set up your ROS environment correctly as explained in http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu section 1.5.
In that case you should be able to use rospack out of the box.

For your information: after setting up my ros fuerte environment, roscd rospack results in: /opt/ros/fuerte/share/rospack

Tinne

---

Originally posted by [Tinne De Laet](https://answers.ros.org/users/137/tinne-de-laet/) with karma: 198 on 2012-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2